# Merging data.frame with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame for apartments classification

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, spatial

I want to merge two objects. The first object (`base`) is a data.frame with information of apartments in Bogotá, including columns as geographic coordinates. The second object (`local`) contains spatial polygons with the localities in Bogotá. Locality is the main administrative division of the city.

I want to classify each apartment according its locality.

My data.frame has the following structure:

```
> str(base)
'data.frame':   37800 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ latitude      : num  4.69 4.64 4.81 4.71 4.6 ...
 $ longitude     : num  -74.2 -74.2 -74 -74.1 -74.1 ...
 $ price         : num  1.88e+09 7.80e+07 1.65e+09 9.50e+08 3.80e+08 ...
 $ area          : num  NA 45 280 193 148 195 NA 167 160 NA ...
 $ bedrooms      : int  NA 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 NA ...
 $ bathrooms     : int  NA 1 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 NA ...
```

On the other side, spatial object `local` is the following:

```
> local
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 20 
extent      : -74.44978, -73.98653, 3.73103, 4.836779  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
variables   : 6
names       :       LocNombre,          LocAAdmini,   LocArea, LocCodigo, SHAPE_Leng,   SHAPE_Area 
min values  : ANTONIO NARIÃ‘O, Acuerdo 117 de 2003,   2060243,        01, 0.06715788, 0.0001677672 
max values  :            USME,   Acuerdo 9 de 1986, 780968758,        20, 1.91494942, 0.0635491267
```

My idea is to obtain something like this:

```
  longitude latitude   precio       area     bedrooms badrooms  locality
1 -74.16257 4.689394 1.88e+09         NA           NA    NA     Chapinero
2 -74.19299 4.637710 7.80e+07         45            3     1     Kennedy
3 -74.02988 4.807232 1.65e+09        280            3     4     Puente Aranda
4 -74.08040 4.713976 9.50e+08        193            3     4     Kennedy
5 -74.06911 4.602593 3.80e+08        148            4     4     Suba
6 -74.05801 4.725810 7.50e+08        195            4     4     Chapinero
```

I will grateful with your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Convert your object `base` into a spatial object.

```
library(sp)    

xy <- base[, c(1,2)] # coordinates of your data.frame

base_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = base,
                                  proj4string = CRS(proj4string(local)))
```

## 2. Use `raster::extract()`

```
library(raster)
raster::extract(local,     # raster or polygon to extract values from
                base_sp,   # points to extract values at
                sp = TRUE) # returns a spatial object
```

---

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. The only addition was to include ``CRS`` function for ``proj4string`` argument since ``proj4string`` function produces a character object.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I was writing on the fly, so I'll fix that now.